# CodeIgniter Validation Not Displaying On Form

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

Another `CI Validation` Error here.  I've tried searching and from what I can see, the code I have is OK.  The validation runs - if I just echo out a "`Validation Failed`" string from the controller, it displays.

But I cannot seem to get it to display in an actual view.  Even if I have a single line in the view (ie echo `validation_errors`(); ), there are no errors output even though it fails `validation`.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

**Controller**

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->form_validation->run('user_add_edit') == FALSE)
    {
        //Validation failed
        $this->load->view('templates/header_generic');
        $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
        $this->load->view('user/add_user_form');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer_generic');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Form validated!";
    }
}
```

**View (Partial)**

```
                        <div class="panel-body">

                        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

                        <?php echo form_open('user/add'); ?>
                            <label for="email">
                                Email Address
                            </label><br />
                            <div class="form-group input-group <?php echo null === form_error('email') || is_null(form_error('email')) ? 'form-group has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                <?php echo form_input($email_attr, set_value('email')); ?>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <?php echo form_error('email');?>
                            <br />
                            <?php echo form_fieldset("Password"); ?>
                            jfkdjflkdjflks
                            <?php echo form_fieldset_close(); ?>
                            <br />
                            <?php echo form_submit("submit", "Add New User", "class='btn btn-success'"); ?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

**Form Validation**

```
$config = array(
'user_add_edit' => array(
    array(
        'field' => 'email',
        'label' => 'Email Address',
        'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]',
        'errors'    => array(
            'required'  => 'You must enter a %s',
            'valid_email'   => '%s is not a valid email address',
            'is_unique'     => 'This email address already exists'
        )
    ),
```

Comment: Oh, I have come across this as a possible error, so I can confirm `base_url` is set in the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `MY_Form_validation.php` improperly set up can mess up with setting of form rules via config file.

**Fix**

In `application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php` - replace your constructor with the below code or just follow the changes below by adding the $config parameter.

```
function __construct($config = array()){
    parent::__construct($config);
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}
```

It's also a **possibility** that the value of $config variable is being overwritten that's happening inside `application/config/form_validation.php`. Check for it as well.

**Alternative:**

Load the form_validation.php config file from the controller method and pass the relevant config item to set_rules(..) like in the following.

```
public function add() {
    $this->load->config('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->config->item('user_add_edit'));

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //Validation failed
        $this->load->view('templates/header_generic');
        $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
        $this->load->view('user/add_user_form');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer_generic');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Form validated!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'm not extending the `CI Form Validation` library though.  I did create the `MY_Form_validation` library extension and try it.  If I just called the usual `$this->load->library(form_validation)` library, nothing changed.  If i called `$this->load->library(MY_Form_validation`, it told me the class `CI Form Validation` wasn't present in my library.  I don't really want to re-write an entire validation library.

Comment: That's fine sir. I added an alternative anyways.

Comment: The alternative got it working.  Weird, but I'm in business. Thank you :)